# localStorage can't get data Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've been having problems with my code in JavaScript again. Here is the part of the code that I'm having trouble with and an explanation:

```
    loadThis.onclick = function(){
        localStorage.setItem("myName", storedTemporary[i].name);
    }

    deleteThis.onclick = function(){

        this.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
        storedTemporary.splice(storedTemporary[i], 1);

    }
```

It splices it from the array and removes it from the screen. But let's say you have 3 items you delete the one and top and the bottom, when you try and load the last one in between it gives an error saying it can't setItem because it "cannot read property undefined". But the interesting thing is that when you console.log the current value of the localStorage item, "myName", it shows the last item's name. This is the for loop. I am using block scoping for it :

```
  var storedTemporary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("temporaryArray"))
  for(let i = 0; i < storedTemporary.length; i++)
  {

  }
```

I am very confused. Please help.

Thank you,
Scratch Cat

Comment: can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your error. It'll be easier for us to help.

Comment: So you want to splice `storedTemporary[i]` right..?

Comment: i am but it doesnt

Comment: seem to splice the right index

Comment: `storedTemporary[i].name`  here `i` is undefined. What is `i` here.

Comment: it's inside the for loop

Comment: `when you try and load the last one in between it gives an error saying it can't setItem because it "cannot read property undefined". ` sounds unclear to me. For loading shouldn't you be doing `getItem`

Comment: no i'm trying to change the local storage to the object's properties when the object that is clicked is loaded.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just storedTemporary.splice(i, 1) ? Since the 1st param is supposed to be an index. storedTemporary[i] looks like an object to me.